# How to asociate cgi extension in windows 10

Tags: windows, perl, cgi

I use Windows 7 with Perl, apache using cgi and every thing was right
Now I have windows 10. The apache runs well but the association of cgi extension with perl does not work.

I have try to fix this but nothing semms to work.

I'm using xampp. I have already edit the htconf file within apache.

In my scripts I have the line `#!/usr/bin/perl` and this is not working. If I change the line to
`#!C:/Perl/bin/perl.exe` then it works, but this is not the best way, because every time i need to upload a script then i have to change it to `#!/usr/bin/perl`

Comment: Strictly speaking, this question isn't about programming, it is about system configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Some basic things need to be cleared here.

1. `#!/usr/bin/perl` is for linux world(shebang). Its doesn't matter on windows. On linux by this statement we are saying - use the 'perl' interpreter present at '/usr/bin/' location  to execute this.
2. On windows, you have give the equivalent in windows world i.e. `#!C:/Perl/bin/perl.exe` in your case.
3. One thing to note here on windows - if you have 'perl' in windows PATH(Env variable) then you don't have the necessity to add `#!C:/Perl/bin/perl.exe`

Most probably in your case you have 'perl' in env variable (System Prop -> Env variable -> System variable) for windows 7. Hence it was taking 'perl' path from there. Again if you have `#!/usr/bin/perl` in top of script on windows, it doesn't matter as there is no such dir on windows.

On windows 10, most probably there is no 'perl' in PATH.
So, 2 possible solution in windows-

1. Either add 'perl' in PATH.
2. Or add `#!C:/Perl/bin/perl.exe` in your script which is the location to perl interpreter. (Not sure, why you are saying not the best way. Do you have any location where it says so ?)

For me, First is better as it will allow my code to work across different OS (and let `#!/usr/bin/perl` be present there). But its up to you.

Answer (score -1):

I have Found it !!
in my script wrote the shebang #!/usr/bin/perl
If i use shebang #!C:/Perl/bin/perl.exe every time y have to upload any update
to the scripts i sholud change the line
The problem was the asociation of the .cgi extension with Perl
so i found the answer by writing a new class in the registry
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.cgi\Shell\ExecCGI\Command(Default) => C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe -wT
and thats it ! it works perfectly.
Thank you very much for your answer i hope this can help any one else